# Acquiring link works using chromedriver but fails using phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to extract a link using the following code

```
def Soup(htmsrc):
    return BeautifulSoup(htmsrc,
                         'html.parser')

def get_html_sel(url, t=15):
    logger.info('Searching: {0}'.format(url))
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        driver.get(url)

        time.sleep(t)

        htmsrc = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
        return (htmsrc)
    except NoSuchWindowException:
        sys.exit('The window closed unexpectedly.')

def get_filehostlink(url):
    for file_hoster_key, file_hoster_value in FILE_HOSTERS.iteritems():
        try:
            link = '{0}{1}'.format(url,file_hoster_value)
            soup = Soup(get_html_sel(link,t=15))
            return soup.find('iframe',src=re.compile(file_hoster_key))['src']
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            continue
        else:
            break

get_filehostlink('http://kissasian.com/Drama/Your-Lie-in-April/Movie?id=33186')
```

It works perfectly using selenium and chromedriver.

However, I find chromedriver cumbersome. So I decided to switch to phantomjs as follows:

```
def get_html_sel(url, t=15):
    logger.info('Searching: {0}'.format(url))
    try:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(t)
        htmsrc = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
        return (htmsrc)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

However, it fails when I use phantomjs. I get the following error in get_filehostlink function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
in get_filehostlink
    return soup.find('iframe',src=re.compile(file_hoster_key))['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the nature of the failure? Perhaps you could provide a stack dump for us?

Comment: I decided to switch to phantomjs... IMHO not the best decision :)

Comment: The line displayed with the diagnostic message doesn't seem to be present in the function you mention. Assuming I'm correct would you please review your question and edit carefully.

Comment: even though it's a headless browser, you can take a screenshot when  the error occurs. It might help.

Comment: @Andersson It never failed for me so far in whatever I did

Comment: Even now, `new_soup` appears just twice on this page, both times in the line associated with the diagnostic message and **not** in the source code above.

Comment: I've taken a quick look, found nothing obvious. If I were you I would strip away as much complication as possible to isolate the precise cause of the failure, and deal with that.

Comment: The problem lies in the get_filehostlink funciton. The video link is extracted using chromedriver but fails when phantomjs is used. Usually, I first scrape using chromedriver and then bring in phantomjs to run it finally.

Comment: Instead of using PhantomJS have you tried using Headless Chrome? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome